# A list of stackexchange sites in order of their release

Tags: discussion

Just out of curiosity, I would like to know that which was the first StackExchange site ever *( I guess it was StackOverflow.com)* and a list of all SE sites in order of their release.

I have googled it but was unable to find what I want.

Just want to know in which order the SE sites appeared. I think this site is the best place to ask such a question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the list of Stack Exchange site order by it's age:

Go to https://stackexchange.com/sites -> change the view to [list view](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list) -> change the order to [oldest](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#oldest).

Comment: thanks dude... that was exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: This misses out on sites that were launched and closed, both SE 1.0 and current.